# R returns list instead of filling in dataframe column

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to use apply() to fill in an additional column in a dataframe and by calling a function I created with each row of the data frame.

The dataframe is called `Hit.Data` has 2 columns `Zip.Code` and `Hits`. Here are a few rows

```
Zip.Code , Hits
97222    , 20
10100    , 35
87700    , 23
```

The apply code is the following:

```
Hit.Data$Zone = apply(Hit.Data, 1, function(x) lookupZone("89000", x["Zip.Code"]))
```

The `lookupZone()` function is the following:

```
lookupZone <- function(sourceZip, destZip){
  sourceKey = substr(sourceZip, 1, 3)
  destKey = substr(destZips, 1, 3)
  return(zipToZipZoneMap[[sourceKey]][[destKey]])
}
```

All the `lookupZone()` function does is take the 2 strings, truncates to the required characters and looks up the values. What happens when I run this code though is that R assigns a list to `Hit.Data$Zone` instead of filling in data row by row.

```
> typeof(Hit.Data$Zone)
[1] "list
```

What baffles me is that when I use apply and just tell it to put a number in it works correctly:

```
> Hit.Data$Zone = apply(Hit.Data, 1, function(x) 2)
> typeof(Hit.Data$Zone)
[1] "double"
```

I know R has a lot of strange behavior around dropping dimensions of matrices and doing odd things with lists but this looks like it should be pretty straightforward. What am I missing? I feel like there is something fundamental about R I am fighting, and so far it is winning.

Comment: what is `zipToZipZoneMap` and what is the `class` of `zipToZipZoneMap[[sourceKey]][[destKey]]`

Comment: It's hard to say exactly, because we don't have `zipToZipZoneMap`. But I feel pretty strongly that you shouldn't even be using `apply` to do this at all.

Comment: zipToZipZoneMap is a hashmap from the hash package. The class of zipToZipZoneMap[[sourceKey]][[destKey]] is [1] "character"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are occasionally looking up non-existing entries in your hashmap, which causes hash to silently return NULL.  Consider:

```
> hash("890", hash("972"=3, "101"=3, "877"=3))[["890"]][["101"]]
[1] 3
> hash("890", hash("972"=3, "101"=3, "877"=3))[["890"]][["100"]]
NULL
```

If `apply` encounters any NULL values, then it can't coerce the result to a vector, so it will return a list.  Same will happen with `sapply`.

You have to ensure that all possible combinations of the first three zip code digits in your data are present in your hash, or you need logic in your code to return `NA` instead of `NULL` for missing entries.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I was pulling my hair out over this. R is useful but I seem to find all of the strange, maddening corners of it. I was not aware that R would convert the result to a list if some of the values were NULL. Very useful information.

Comment: @MatthewCrews, one way to try to debug this issue is to produce the smallest possible data set that has the problem, and then add a `browser()` statement inside the function `apply` uses to see what's going on.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I'm still learning how to debug R and the silent failures can really stump me.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's hard to diagnose without knowing what `ZiptoZipZoneMap(...)` is doing, but you could try this:

```
Hit.Data$Zone <- sapply(Hit.Data$Zip.Code, function(x) lookupZone("89000", x))
```

Comment: sapply() still returns a list